# silhouette rest seed : how to use a social provider?

Tags: facebook, scala, playframework, oauth-2.0

https://github.com/merle-/silhouette-rest-seed

I am trying to use this as I don't want to use the scala.html template files, and this seemed to do exactly what I wanted. I can CURL to create a user and get a token, but I don't know what to do with the redirects when trying to authenticate with a social provider, such as Facebook. There don't seem to be any instructions, either. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you filled in the details about the facebook app in `silhouette.conf` file.

Answer (score 0):

The readme gets you to the point where you have signed up a user and with the credentials POST retrieved the X-Auth-Token. 
After a little debugging you will submit a POST request to the auth/link route to associate the user with the returned X-Auth-Token with a social provider as in:

```
http :9000/auth/link/facebook 'accessToken=xxxxx' X-Auth-Token:tokenfromearlier
```

Note the syntax of httpie is specific and must use = for json and : for headers. You obtain accessToken from here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/

This will return the following JSON:

```
{
    "message": "link with social completed!",
    "status": "ok"
}
```

Not yet sure how to accomplish the next step which is to invoke the
/auth/signin/facebook POST route as this requires the ID of the provider and I am still figuring out the fb graph access approach.